# nextcloud and mariadb (both) on docker: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, mariadb

I've been trying to set up [Nextcloud](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/nextcloud/) and [MariaDB](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/mariadb/) with the Linux server images and hit my road block when I want to get through the first run wizard of Nextcloud:

[image: Error message incl. all settings of first run wizard]

### Problem

I.e. the first time wizard gives me `Error while trying to create admin user: Failed to connect to the database: An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`.

### Question:

Where is that coming from and how to solve the problem?

### System

I'm using [Amahi 11](https://wiki.amahi.org/index.php/Amahi_11_Install) and have installed docker from the repositories. Docker verision:

```
  Client:
 Version:           18.09.0
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.4
 Git commit:        4d60db4
 Built:             Wed Nov  7 00:48:52 2018
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.0
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.4
  Git commit:       4d60db4
  Built:            Wed Nov  7 00:19:08 2018
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

I am starting nextcloud and mariadb with docker-compose. Following the content for mariadb:

```
version: '2'
  services:
    mariadb:
      image: linuxserver/mariadb
      container_name: mariadb
      environment:
        - PUID=XX
        - PGID=YYY
        - MYSQL_ROOT_USER=root
        - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
        - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      volumes:
        - <path/to/my/folder>:/config
      ports:
        - 3307:3306
      restart: unless-stopped
```

### Already tried:

1. A lot of research, which came up empty or lead me to do the next point:
2. So from the error info I started checking if the database actually exists:`sudo docker exec -it mariadb bash`. There I figured, that access to command-line with 'mysql' for root was denied because the password was not set. (mmmh... is ther something wrong with my docker-compose-file?)
   Anyway I corrected that one with `mysql -u root -pSECRET`and `mysql -u root --password=SECRET`. With `show databases;` I found no `nextcloud` database. (There MUST be something wrong with my docker-compose-file.) So I created it as well (`create database nextcloud;`). Database is now shown properly and I found it in `<path/to/my/folder>`. **Result:** No change, problem still there.
3. I did some more editing with on my docker-compose-file:

   ```
   version: '2'
     services:
       mariadb:
         image: linuxserver/mariadb
         container_name: mariadb
         environment:
           - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
           - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
           - PUID=XX
           - PGID=YYY
         volumes:
           - <path/to/my/folder>:/config
         ports:
           - 3307:3306
         restart: unless-stopped
   ```

So I changed the hierarchy and eliminated the `MYSQL_ROOT_USER=root`line. When restarting I can `mysql -u root --password=SECRET` and show the `nextcloud` database. YET, I am not sure, if these changes remained in the volume from my last (manual) changes. **Result:** Problem still there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Docker I get the error: "SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[2002\] No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40075065/using-docker-i-get-the-error-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 5):

I changed `localhost` -> `mariadb` and it worked!

Answer (score 4):

Just for curiousity I started playing around with the localhost-port. I chose 3307 because my host-system has a mariadb running on 3306, which I do not want to use. So altering port `localhost:3307` to `localhost:WXYZ` - you name it gives the same error... mmmh - changeing `localhost` to `<your host-IP>`!!!

**SUCCESS**

Answer (score 4):

I had to use `nextcloud-mariadb:3306` as the connection string. I figured it out by running `$ docker ps -a` which lists the name and the port.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution:

As other answers have mentioned, the solution is *don't* use `localhost`.
Even changing to `127.0.0.1` appears to be sufficient *(see note below)

## Explanation:

`No such file or directory` is the result of mysql attempting to connect over a local socket. This happens when either of these settings is set to `localhost`:

1. `Database host` field of the WebUI
2. environment variable `MYSQL_HOST`

***Note**: in the case of #2, it is not sufficient to "fix" the `Database host` field in the WebUI, the environment variable `MYSQL_HOST` **always** takes precedence.
(This is true as of NextCloud version `25.0.0.18`)

Answer (score 1):

I changed the database name(localhost:PORT -> container_name), and it worked!

By the way, the [localhost:PORT] wroked well before!

Answer (score 0):

When you run Nextcloud in docker, add `--link mariadb:mariadb`. You can then use `mariadb` to replace `localhost`

Answer (score 0):

I had to use my custom server hostname, instead of `localhost`. On Linux you can get it by executing the command `hostname`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem when I changed the Nexcloud `MYSQL_HOST` environment parameter from `localhost` to database service/image name (in my case `MYSQL_HOST: mysql` ) in the `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql-nextcloud
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
     ...
    volumes:
      ...

  app:
    image: nextcloud
    container_name: nextcloud
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:80
    links:
      - mysql
    volumes:
      ...
    environment:
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ...
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ...
      MYSQL_USER: ...
      MYSQL_HOST: mysql
```